# Javascript How to convert a decimal number to a string with specific number of decimal places

Tags: javascript, number-formatting, decimalformat

In a javascript code, I have a requirement to format a decimal number to a specific number of decimal places and get its exact string representation. For example, If the number is 999999999.9 and the number of decimal places is 8, then the expected value should be "999999999.90000000"

When the Number.toFixed(8) is used it returns a rounded value which is not what I want. Please refer the below code

```
var num = 999999999.9
var string_rep = num.toFixed(8)

>> the value of string_rep is "999999999.89999998"
```

I used num.toString() and tried to manually format the decimal part by adding/removing digits, but it does not work for very small numbers like "0.00000008" as the function toString() returns
the scientific notation, i.e. something like "9e-8"

So what should be the proper approach for this?

Comment: You can do : convert it to string, split with dot, padright with 0 decimal part and concat them.

Comment: @Eldar I have tried it, there is an issue when converting small numbers to string as it gives the scientific notation like "9e-8". I have explained it in my post, please read

Comment: You've got the proper approach, you've just forgotten that JavaScript uses IEEE floating point numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Number.prototype.toLocaleString` will do the trick

```
    num.toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 8, useGrouping: false})//"999999999.90000000"
```

Comment: This works exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot for the answer